# "An error has occurred. Please try again later" in my iframe

Tags: html, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I copy and paste a YouTube link inside my `iframe` tag and I got the following message when I play the video

> "An error has occurred. Please try again later".

I put the embed within inside the link.

Here's my code:

```
<iframe width="450" height="200"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=xZs6nCUQuuM">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Do you happen to be running this locally from your filesystem? I'm not sure why this'd happen, but I think it should definitely work from something like a SimpleHTTPServer, rather than just an opened HTML file

Comment: @Daneolog I was able to reproduce it. It's none of it.

Answer (score 6):

I just found out that you could just go to the desired Youtube video, click share, click embed and then copy paste it to your code then viola. It's perfectly in my page, just needed some width and height styling to get the desired size. Anyways thank y'all for putting effort and time for answering my question, I really appreciated it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<iframe width="450" height="200"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xZs6nCUQuuM">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your info plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <!--Not a recommended way, there are better solutions available-->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```